# Unable to install nginx as part of LEMP - Nextcloud setup

Tags: server, 20.04, nginx, raspberrypi, nextcloud

I already search and tried solutions for the error message i get but i cant seem to install nginx as a first step of  building a LEMP - Nextcloud setup on a Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.4.

This i what i get

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# apt update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# apt install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgd3
  libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream libtiff5
  libwebp6 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 nginx-common nginx-core
Suggested packages:
  libgd-tools fcgiwrap nginx-doc ssl-cert
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgd3
  libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream libtiff5
  libwebp6 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 nginx nginx-common nginx-core
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2775 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8642 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-dejavu-core.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 loading files list file for package 'libmpfr6:arm64': cannot open /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmpfr6:arm64.list (Structure needs cleaning)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#
```

I also seem to get alot of these dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: . i think i have reinstalled the os a couple of times as i have encountered some apt update and upgrade that always result to the error message. this was the first instance i didnt encountered that but now face issue installing nginx.

Answer (score 0):

"Structure needs cleaning" means that your filesystem is corrupt.

1. Run `fsck` on that filesystem. Since this seems to be your system partition, you CAN'T boot from it. fsck must be run while the partition is unmounted.

   - Move the media to a different Ubuntu system, DON'T mount it, DON'T boot from it, and run fsck on it using that other running system.
   - Alternately, you can boot a Live image, but that's sometimes a problem on a Pi.
2. Repeated corruption may indicate a faulty media:

   - If it's a HDD, look up how to run a SMART test on it.
   - If it's an SD card, try a different card...or a different reader. Readers go bad, too.

Comment: thanks could reformating via etcher with different OS on the sd card could have broke the SD card?

Comment: Thanks, your right, it was related to the SD card. But SD card was not broken. It was somewhat related to me pushing SD card all the way in the card slot of the PI. Maybe how my pi was made not sure. But if i just insert it and make sure its not all push all the way to the end it works flawless but tried to do oposite i get all kind of read error.

Comment: Edited to address faulty readers. Thanks for the update!